# Exception: Gradle build failed to produce an .apk file. It's likely that this file was generated under C:\Users\airbu but the tool couldn't find it

Tags: flutter, dart

Exception: Gradle build failed to produce an .apk file. It's likely that this file was generated under C:\Users\airbu\Desktop\KREAAPPS\hotel_booking_app\build, but the tool couldn't find it.